# convert 0-255 into decimal between 0-1

Tags: arithmetic

What I am trying to do is convert the color values $0-255$ into a decimal form between $0-1$ for example $127.5 = 0.50$ or $191.25 = 0.75$. I know this is simple math but the problem is that with the program I am writing a $0$ represents `ON` and a $1$ represents `OFF`  so with a color code of $255$ it should actually be equal to $0.0$ and with a color code value of $0$ it should equal $1.0$. Can someone please tell me how to solve this math has never been a strong point of mine.

Comment: Shouldn't this be on StackOverflow, not Mathematics?

Comment: I posed this on StackOverflow and actually got the same answer as below but for some reason I guess I was not doing the equation right and kept coming up with the wrong answer.

Comment: That would be correct

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about you use the function?

> > $$f(x)=1-\frac{x}{255}$$

Comment: this works for 127.5 but for 191.25 you would get 0.25. the subtraction from 1 is not necessary.

Comment: the 0.25 for 191.25 is what I actually want in this case it seems strange and backwards I know

Comment: @franklin That is the OP's intent behavior, so the subtraction from 1 is in fact necessary to perform the OP's task.

Comment: ah. thanks @AJMansfield. actually then this would be the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

All you need really is $f(x) = x/255$ for example if you put the input color as $x$ your output should be $f(x)$ as in, $x = 127.5$, $f(x) = 0.5$. It's a proportion of your input value to the entire spectrum, 255.